# RegEx to remove two whitespaces before end ol line

Tags: java, regex

I want 2 whitespaces to be replaced with a whitespace @ end of every line...

```
String msg =  "ABCD  5320061   \n"+
          "ABCD  5320061   \n";
System.out.println(msg.length());
String a1 = "[  \\s]{2}$";
String a2 = " ";
String x = msg.replaceAll(a1, a2);
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(x.length());
```

But the output is :

```
34
ABCD  5320061   
ABCD  5320061  

33
```

Only the last line end white space is replaced with a space

Comment: Why don't you just use `.trim()` to remove the white space on the ends?

Comment: @rabbitguy he's trying to trim the whitespace from each line in a single string, so he would also have to split the string by newlines.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You can use: `msg.replaceAll("(?m)\\s{2}$", "");`

Comment: Actually, the `\s` also matches a newline, so the expression above will match more than what is expected - see https://regex101.com/r/bG7aV7/1

Comment: How about `(  (\n|$))`?
  https://regex101.com/r/qT4oO6/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want 2 whitespaces to be replaced with a whitespace @ end of every line

To match the end of the *line* you need to use a [**`Pattern.MULTILINE`** modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE), or its embedded (inline) version `(?m)`.

Also, to only match horizontal whitespace, you may either use `[^\S\r\n]`, or `[\p{Zs}\t]`.

So, I'd go with

```
String x = msg.replaceAll("(?m)[\\p{Zs}\t]{2}$", a2);
```

or

```
String x = msg.replaceAll("(?m)[^\\S\r\n]{2}$", a2);
```